# T-Sql Multiple Criteria On Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

#### Scenario

I'm using SQL Server 2005
I have a T-Sql query that has multiple criteria to search on the WHERE clause.
I'm certain that I'm doing this in a very inefficient and long way round.
How can I ensure that I don't have to manually type out all the criteria?
Instead I want to pass in the criteria via a SELECT * clause.

#### Current Query Code

```
SELECT * FROM tblBooks
WHERE BookID = 1
OR BookID = 4
OR BookID = 5
OR BookID = 7
OR BookID = 8
OR BookID = 11
OR BookID = 14
```

#### Proposed PSEUDO Query Code

```
SELECT * FROM tblBooks
WHERE BookID = (SELECT BookID FROM tblAuthors WHERE Genre = 'Fiction')
```

#### Comments On Code

As you can see from the proposed pseudo code, the idea is to select a list of BookIDs from another query and pass this list of criteria into the actual query itself.
How do I go about doing this correctly?

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you looking for something like this

```
SELECT * FROM tblBooks
WHERE BookID in (SELECT BookID FROM tblAuthors WHERE Genre = 'Fiction')
```

This will return all the data in the table tblAuthors if book id is there

Answer (score 3):

YOur pseudo code, isn't too pseudo.  Change the = to IN and your done.

```
SELECT * FROM tblBooks 
WHERE BookID IN (SELECT BookID FROM tblAuthors WHERE Genre = 'Fiction')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a join:

```
SELECT  b.*
FROM    tblBooks b
        INNER JOIN
                tblAuthors a
                ON b.BookID = a.BookID
WHERE   a.Genre = 'Fiction'
```

I assume these are not your real tables? I can't see why the Genre property is not on the book itself. Many authors write across multiple genres (take Iain Banks for example).

Comment: Books are in genres **and** authors write in genres, so I would have genres be a table of it's own with join tables between both books and genres (assuming a book can be in multiple genres even if that's not typical) and authors and genres.

Comment: Yes, certainly a separate lookup table for genres would be sensible, with a link table between authors and genres. Not sure about books...

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing alternatives out there:

```
SELECT tblBooks.* 
  FROM tblBooks 
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM tblAuthors 
                WHERE tblBooks.BookID = tblAuthors.BookID
                  AND tblAuthors.Genre = 'Fiction');
```

---

```
SELECT tblBooks.*
  FROM tblBooks
 WHERE tblBooks.BookID = ANY
(SELECT tblAuthors.BookID
   FROM tblAuthors
  WHERE tblAuthors.Genre = 'Fiction');
```